# Finding elements in specific index between two lists using a function or other

Tags: python-3.x

How do I define a function where for a and b it would return 7 and 5
or `a[0]` and `b[0]` and `a[4]` and `b[4]`. The problem is the length of both lists could change at any time...

I've tried:

```
  if a[0]== b[0]: 
        print(a[0])
```

but if the length of lists changes then it would eventually return a list Index out of range error.

Any help is much appreciated.

- `a = [7, 5, 9, 3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5]`
- `b = [7, 3, 3, 5, 5, 2, 1, 5, 2, 5, 2, 9, 8, 6]`

Comment: This needs more clarification if you're still interested in an answer. Are you trying to find all differences between the two lists?

Answer (score 0):

Zip two lizts with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and iterate over it:

```
a = [7, 5, 9, 3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5]
b = [7, 3, 3, 5, 5, 2, 1, 5, 2, 5, 2, 9, 8, 6]

for a_i, b_i in zip(a, b):
    if a_i == b_i:
        print(a_i, b_i)

Out:
7, 7
5, 5
```

or define it as a fiunction:

```
def extract_matches(a, b):
    result = []
    for a_i, b_i in zip(a, b):
        if a_i == b_i:
            result.append((a_i, b_i))
    return result

matches = extract_matches(a, b)    
matches
Out:
[(7, 7), (5, 5)]
```

How the `zip` works. `zip` function always zips lists by shorter. It returns a generator, so you should iterate it:

```
list(zip([1,2,3], [1,2]))  
Out:
[(1, 2), (1, 2)]  # list of pairs

list(zip([], [1,2,3]))  
Out:
[]  # length of shorter is 0, so you get zero length list
```